# specify data type in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Runs table and this is my query

```
SELECT (pass*100)/total as pass from Runs where runId=1
```

I want the data type of the result returned to be `decimal` type.

How do I specify that ?

I did this after the query :

decimal.TryParse(reader["pass"].ToString(), out d1); d1 should be 83.4 but it is 83

Comment: convert the whole to `decimal`

Answer (score 1):

use `cast` to convert it to decimal and provide precision and scale accordingly

```
select cast((pass*100)/total as decimal(4,2)) from Runs where runId=1
```

Comment: I did this after the query : decimal.TryParse(reader["pass"].ToString(), out d1); di should be 83.4 but it is 83

Comment: why to parse it again when you get that in query

Comment: how to get the value then ?

Comment: i think I need to convert either pass or total to decimal type.Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST((pass*100)/total as decimal) as pass from Runs where runId=1
```

(Provide DECIMAL precision and scale of your choice...)

Comment: I did this after the query :               decimal.TryParse(reader["pass"].ToString(), out d1);  di should be 83.4 but it is 83